# custom annotation in jsf2 : where to implement logic

Tags: java, jsf-2, annotations, managed-bean

I have a jsf project and I want to write my custom annotation in it.

annotaion is:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation {
    String value();
}
```

in beans i want to use this annotation:

```
public class JobBean {

    @MyAnnotaion(value = "Hello")
    public void start() {
        //start
    }

    public void stop() {
        //stop
    }
}
```

there is some view that trigger the `JobBean`'s methods.

now i want to print "Hello" when the `start` method called. where can I write my annotation logic?